# Date_Sub(NOW) error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get errors

> 'NOW' is not a recognized built-in function name.

SQL stored procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM BlogPost WHERE BlogDate <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Comment: What server product are you using?

Comment: No wonder then. Your SQL snippet is of different flavour, very likely MySQL's.

Answer (score 6):

In SQL Server, what you are trying to do might look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM BlogPost
WHERE BlogDate <= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM BlogPost WHERE BlogDate <= DATEADD(Month , -1,  GETDATE())
```

Comment: I get this error now
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Procedure SelectAllBlogPost, Line 5
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: SELECT *, 
       COALESCE(c.TotalComments,0) as TotalComments
FROM   BlogPost 
       INNER JOIN BlogUser 
         ON BlogPost.BlogUserId = BlogUser.BlogUserId 
       INNER JOIN Category 
         ON BlogPost.CategoryId = Category.CategoryId 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT BlogPostId, 
                          COUNT(BlogPostId) TotalComments
                   FROM   BlogComment
                   GROUP BY BlogPostId) c
         ON c.BlogPostId = BlogPost.BlogPostId
         WHERE BlogPost.BlogDate <= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
ORDER  BY BlogPost.BlogPostId DESC